# Text appearing under image

Tags: html, css, image, background

So I'm learning HTML and CSS, and I have an image as a background. But when I try to add text on it, it covers it. Here's my CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.img{
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('126.42.jpg');
    position: fixed;
}
body{
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ATS7V/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
background-image: url('http://s29.postimg.org/lltw25n07/126_42.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

To your body

```
body{
z-index: 99;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('http://s29.postimg.org/lltw25n07/126_42.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcsl/ATS7V/12/

Comment: Well how would I make it a fixed background then?

Comment: What do you mean with a fixed background?

Comment: Fixed background. So that then I can scroll and it won't move with the text.

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't understand. Use   background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
http://jsfiddle.net/jcsl/ATS7V/10/

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say text is covered, you want it to be displayed.

So do the following:

```
h1{
 position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

<div class="img">
 <h1>test</h1>
<h1>test</h1>
<h1>test</h1>   

</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ATS7V/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your `z-index` property is setting the image on top of everything else.

Change it to:

```
z-index: -1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ATS7V/1/